# Apache Common Daemons : PrunServ --StartPath parameter overriding PATH on windows

Tags: windows, windows-services, procrun, apache-commons-daemon

I am running a java program on windows 10 workstation.

I wanted to run my java program as a service so i used apache commons tool prunserv
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html

Issue is my java program runs some windows shell commands inside it like `cmd \c netstat -rn` but when i start my java program as a service and specify StartPath as some directory. commands inside my java programs fail with error like below

```
Error executing command : [cmd, /c, netstat, -rn], Output is : 'netstat' is not recognized as an 
internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I feel like StartPath argument of procrun is overriding PATH variables like C:\Windows\System32 thus making command inside java program to fail

*--StartPath        Working path for the start image executable.*

How should i deal with this situation ?

Let me know if you need any further details.

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Procrun(Prunserv) provides an option for setting Environment

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html

```
++Environment="PATH='C:\Users\Public\agent\jre\bin';'C:\Windows\system32'"
```

I added C:\Windows\system32 in Environment and it worked fine.

> Note : Environment option in prunserv is List of environment variables
> that will be provided to the service in the form key=value. They are
> separated using either # or ; characters. If you need to embed either # or ; character within a value put them inside single quotes.